# Не выводится список в onCreate

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

Никак не могу понять, в чем дело: 
Когда загружаю в onCreate список listView - ничего не показывается, как только стоит выключить и включить обратно экран - список выводится.
Помогите понять причину, я в ступоре.
Код AsyncTask:

```
    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        backendlessInitialize();


        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowPUSH.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(text1);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(text2);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        Typeface avenirnextregular= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "avenirnextregular.ttf");
        ((TextView) mProgressDialog.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android"))).setTypeface(avenirnextregular);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<notifications>();
        try {

            Backendless.Persistence.of( notifications.class).find(new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<notifications>>(){
                @Override
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<notifications> notification) {

                    for (notifications pushes: notification.getData()){

                        notifications push = new notifications();
                        push.setPush((String) pushes.getPush());
                        push.setDatePush((String) pushes.getDatePush());

                        worldpopulationlist.add(push);

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
                    Log.i ("listView33", "error: " + backendlessFault.getMessage());
                }});

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pushes_listview);

        adapter = new PUSHListViewAdapter(ShowPUSH.this, worldpopulationlist);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Полный код Активити:

```
public class ShowPUSH extends Activity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
PUSHListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<notifications> worldpopulationlist;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
String text1;
String text2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.push_listview_main);



    setBack();
 //   setIcons();

    SharedPreferences preferences_blurSwitch = getSharedPreferences("TEMP_BLUR", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Integer blurSwitch = preferences_blurSwitch.getInt("TEMP_BLUR", 0);
    if (blurSwitch == 1){

    }
    else{
        blur();
    }
    swipe();



    // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

}

public void swipe(){
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {


    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    }, 4000);
}

 public void backendless(){

SharedPreferences YOUR_APP_ID_sp = getSharedPreferences("BACKENDLESS_APP_ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences YOUR_SECRET_KEY_sp = getSharedPreferences("BACKENDLESS_SECRET_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences APP_VERSION_sp = getSharedPreferences("BACKENDLESS_APP_VERSION", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String YOUR_APP_ID = YOUR_APP_ID_sp.getString("BACKENDLESS_APP_ID", "");
String YOUR_SECRET_KEY = YOUR_SECRET_KEY_sp.getString("BACKENDLESS_SECRET_KEY", "");
String APP_VERSION = APP_VERSION_sp.getString("BACKENDLESS_APP_VERSION", "");

Backendless.initApp( this, YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_SECRET_KEY, APP_VERSION );
}
```

Код Адаптера:

```
public class PUSHListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Typeface avenirnextbold;
Typeface avenirnextregular;
// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<notifications> worldpopulationlist = null;
private ArrayList<notifications> arraylist;

public PUSHListViewAdapter(Context context, List<notifications> worldpopulationlist) {

    this.context = context;






    this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<notifications>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);





    }

}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;
    ImageView flag;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    android.util.Log.i ("listView33", "worldpopulationlist.size(): " + worldpopulationlist.size());
    return worldpopulationlist.size();


}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.push_listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.rank = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.push_message);
        holder.country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_push);



    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }



        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPush());
        holder.country.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getDatePush());
        android.util.Log.i ("listView33", "older.rank.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPush());: " + worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPush());




        }


        holder.country.setTypeface(avenirnextbold);
        holder.rank.setTypeface(avenirnextregular);
    }
    catch(Exception nullEx){



    }
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, дело в том, что у вас в `doInBackground` запускается ещё одна асинхронная задача и, в итоге, `onPostExecute` исполняется до её завершения. В итоге изначально список ваш - пуст.

В любом случае наполнять список данными внутри самого `doInBackground` - плохая идея. Вам надо его там формировать, передавать в `onPostExecute` и именно в нём уже добавлять данные в список активити и после этого передавать список в адаптер. Список не тот, что получен в `onPostExecute`, а тот, что в активити лежит.

Добавлять данные в список надо методом `addAll`, а не переназачением объекта списка ссылке.

---

В активити изначально инициализируйте список с данными.

```
private List<notifications> worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Задача скачивания должна выглядеть так:

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<notifications>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<notifications> doInBackground(Void... params) {

       ArrayList<notifications> worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<notifications>();
       //наполняем данными и возвращаем их
       return worldpopulationlist;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<notifications> result) {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pushes_listview);
        worldpopulationlist.clear();
        worldpopulationlist.addAll(result);
        adapter = new PUSHListViewAdapter(ShowPUSH.this, worldpopulationlist);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user207840, немного кода добавил.

Comment: Вы были правы: я изменил Backendless.Persistence.of( Contact.class).findLast( new AsyncCallback<Contact>(){ .....    на Contact lastContact = Backendless.Persistence.of( Contact.class ).findLast(); ( то есть просто переделал запрос на синхронный), и всё стало работать. Благодарю!

Comment: Спасибо также за пример!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: В onPostExecute ? Я попробовал: к сожалению, не помогает - тот же эффект.  Возможно, у Вас есть другие предположения?

Comment: вы что-нибудь вызываете в оnResume()? приведите код активити

Comment: в onResume() ничего не вызываю. Его и нет даже в этом классе. Обновил весь код Активити, убрав точно несущественные войды. Возможно, может помочь код Адаптера (я его добавил в вопрос)?

Comment: Заметил, что тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135766/listview-doesnt-show-any-items-when-oncreate-is-called/36136572 синонимичная ситуация, правда, и тот предложенный вариант не подходит.